# Is it possible to late bind into an arbitrary application?

Tags: c#, late-binding

I've been extracting text from the various Office programs (Word, PowerPoint etc.) using late binding via `IID_IDispatch` and `AccessibleObjectFromWindow()` and then calling functions/getching properties using `InvokeMember()`.

I was wondering - is this possible to do with any application? Currently I'm trying to extract text from, for example, Adobe Acrobat Reader and PDF-XChange Viewer.

Any other way you could achieve the same functionality?

Comment: Not *any* application, just ones with a friendly COM interface...

Comment: Is there any way to tell if an application has a friendly COM interface?

Comment: A good starting point is to run OLEView, and see if it has a registered type library. It does, you can try creating an application object using `Activator.CreateInstance`, using the application ID, and cast the result to a `dynamic` object. Then you can have a play from there. If you Google the application looking for 'COM automation' or 'COM interface', you'll probably find example code out there for many apps.

Comment: Adobe Acrobat Automation SDK is here, for example: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/downloads.html